# How I can store files in session with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating a form spread around in a few pages, these pages are loaded with jQuery (so the page doesn't refresh) and one of these pages let's the user to add files.

I store all the information in the session (`$_SESSION`) so when the user changes between the pages all the information they wrote is still there.

My problem is with the files. When the user gets to the last page and submits the form even if I have the files stored in the session and the upload scripts returns success, it won't add the files in the server folder.

I think the problem is that the temp file stored in this case in `xampp/temp` is deleted when the user changes the page, does someone knows a solution?

I tested the same code with a direct upload (only one page) as I saw in w3schools tutorial and that worked so XAMPP should be configured right.

This is my code:

```
    $target_dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/project/uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_SESSION['support']['relatorios-tecnicos']["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        return "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    
    // Check file size
    if ($_SESSION['support']['relatorios-tecnicos']["size"] > 500000) {
        return "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType == "exe") {
        return "Sorry, we don't accept executables.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        return "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
        try{
            if (is_dir($target_dir) && is_writable($target_dir)) {
                move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['support']['relatorios-tecnicos']["tmp_name"], $target_file);
            } else {
                return 'Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist: '.$target_dir;
            }
            return "The file ". $_SESSION['support']['relatorios-tecnicos']["tmp_name"] . " has been uploaded.";
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return $e;
        }
    }
```

Code that switches between pages:

```
//Im working with routes so with the value in "option" I know the file to load
var changePage = function(x){
    var url = "solicitar-apoio/apoio?option=" + x;
    $("#live-form").hide().load(url).fadeIn('800');
}
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: PHP stores file uploads only temporarily, and only within the context of serving the request in which they were uploaded, so you need to call `move_uploaded_file()` immediately upon receiving the upload if you've got a multi-request workflow. Store _that_ file path in `$_SESSION` for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Saving in `$_SESSION`

It is not impossible to save file content or anything in `$_SESSION` but it is not wise! Especially if session storage is in Memory or DB. So consider never doing anything like that! because it's a bad practice and it can impact your performance!

### PHP temp files

You can use the temp file uploaded to PHP `tmp` directory. but you should consider that uploaded file will be deleted when the request execution is finished!

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed

So if you want to use your file in another page consider my proposal below.

### The solution

You should move the uploaded file instantly. Then save the `name` or `id` along with the `timestamp` in a table of your database. Now:

1. If a user uses that file you remove corresponding record at the DB.
2. At the end of some requests you can query all the old files and delete them.

Successfully Done!

**Notice: To not interrupting user execution you can use a [Cron Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to check and remove old files. It is Included even in CPanel!**